# Is there any way in BindingSource to know the values changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, bindingsource

I'm using a `BindingSource` in a windows forms application, there are many controls was bound with a BindingSource.

I don't want to monitor the controls to get the changes, can I know if a value changed from the BindingSource by an event?

I looked for an event in it, but I didn't find.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [BindingSource.ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged.aspx) event.

> The ListChanged event occurs when there is a change to the membership or metadata of the underlying list represented by the List property. For example, this event is raised when items are added, removed, or moved, or the DataSource or DataMember properties change.